# Cannot connect to internet from docker container

Tags: docker

```
$ docker run -it busybox
Unable to find image 'busybox:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
90e01955edcd: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:2a03a6059f21e150ae84b0973863609494aad70f0a80eaeb64bddd8d92465812
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
/ # ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
285 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
/ #
```

Why does this happen? What can I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was behind a proxy and the solution was to set the ip number of the proxy in ~/.docker/config.json instead of the name.

Answer (score 1):

hi can you check your network interface eth0 or whatever name
 or restart network interface 
ifdown eth0

ifup eth0

if instance in vpc then check NAT or internet gateway is there to make connection to internet